# How to navigate New Page without Tabs react-native

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to navigate from the page in tabs to the new page without tabs ( or/and header) . but technically it is changed and opened with the tabs and header . I don't know how can do this... it's my project's directory :

```
.
. 
.
src
  -components
    -Page1.js
    -Page2.js
App.js
.
.
.
```

the App.js codes:

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Page 1 from './components/Page1';  
import Page 2 from './components/Page2';

export default TabNav = TabNavigator (
  {
    Page1: { screen: Page1 },
    Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  },
);
```

and now in Page1 & Page2 I create a class Page3(in Page1) and Page4(in Page4) and coding the same codes above and when I want to click to the text (with StackNavigator) the page navigate to the new component that I want!

the **problem** is that the Page3 & Page4 run in the Tab and I don't want (I wanna navigate them in blank page without any Tabs or Header or...)  how I can programming to do that? help me. thanks :)

Comment: is Page3 a stack sibling to Page1?

Comment: yes, 1-> 3 and 2-> 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution. problem is solved when I navigate to the Page3(4) and in `navigationOptions` set `tabBarVisible: false` to hide **TabBar**or `header: null` for not showing **Header**.
here is the example:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Page2 from './../pages/Page2';
import Page4 from "../pages/Page4";

export default Home= StackNavigator ({

    Page2: { screen : Page2},
    Page4: { screen: Page4,
    navigationOptions:{
        tabBarVisible: false,
        header: null
    }}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**step one**: initial navigation and your screens

```
import { StackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation'; 
const App = StackNavigator({ 
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }, 
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }, 
});
```

**step two**: navigate to some page

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', }; 
  render() { 
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return ( 
      <Button title="Go to Jane's profile" onPress={() => navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' }) } />
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: are  'Home' and 'Profile' in children to tab navigator? if yes then i think even 'profile' will have tab bar. Have you tried this?

Comment: So is your problem solved? I dont see a approved on this answer.

Comment: @soroush-chehresa dear soroush your solution help me add StackNavigator and as you see I solved my own problem. (Damet garme :) )